# How to scroll table layout in horizontal and vertical in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am totally confused in table layout scroll. I have to implement table with horizontal and vertical scrolling. I have also saw table fix header example but tablefixheader sample have used adapter to set data but i require add-view method in table layout.
    I have used below code but it couldn't support both ways scrolling

```
      <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:fadeScrollbars="false">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayoutId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This is how I implemented it and works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
 <ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/layout" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"         
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"     
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:fillViewport="true"> 

    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/horizontalView" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tlGridTable" >   
        </TableLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Take a look at this code and see if this helps.

Comment: Great +1. You should add a little explanation why it works =)

Comment: My guess would be that it works because of this line  android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" in both scrollViews that the OP has missed.

Comment: You should change the outsideInset value to outsideOverlay, otherwise the TableLayout's width won't match your parents width. It won't fill up the screen.

Comment: I have some problem in ScrollView please help me, i tried your solution but not success  @EmilAdz  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588702/why-my-scrollview-not-working-properly

Comment: @KarthiVenture, the question you asked is not related to this code. This code design to enable horizontal and vertical scroll, where you want to apply only vertical scroll in you case.

Comment: okay thanks bro but how to fix my problem ? what i make mistake? @EmilAdz

Answer (score 5):

add like this

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_pins"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ScrollView>
```