# How to add both horizontal and vertical view in a single activity.

Tags: android, scroll

I want to add horizontal and vertical scroll in one activity. But i can not add both. I have follow some examples. But my application crashes and force close.

I have follow this links.

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623337/how-to-scroll-table-layout-in-horizontal-and-vertical-in-android)
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771455/android-how-to-allow-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling)

My requirement is:-

[image]

Top is horizontal scroll, Bottom is vertical scroll.

I have try like this:-

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
   <TextView android:id ="@+id/labelA"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Name:"
   android:layout_x="0px"
   android:layout_y="5px"
/>

<EditText android:id="@+id/edtInput"
   android:layout_x="0px"
      android:layout_y="40px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
/>

<TextView android:id ="@+id/labelB"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Email:"
   android:layout_x="0px"
   android:layout_y="110px"
/>

<EditText android:id="@+id/edtInputA"
   android:layout_x="0px"
      android:layout_y="150px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
/>

<Button android:id ="@+id/btnClick"
   android:layout_width="180px"
   android:layout_height="70px"
   android:text="Open New Screen"
   android:textSize="14px"
   android:layout_x="0px"
      android:layout_y="235px"
/>



    </LinearLayout>    
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please let me know any idea to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the problem. Maybe this might help to achieve it, you should put all in `RelativeLayout` and add its attributes as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout 
     ... >

     <HorizontalScrollView
         android:id="@+id/header"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >  
         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
             <!-- other views -->
         </LinearLayout>
     </HorizontalScrollView>

     <ScrollView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@id/header" >
         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
             <!-- other views -->
         </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if this helps.